# Consider ODE ; find solution(s).

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$x^{2} y''+ 6xy' + 6y = 4e^{2x}$ ; $y'(0)=1, y(0)=1$

Solutions?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $X$ is the same as $x$.  The general solution of this inhomogeneous Euler equation is 
$$ y(x) = \dfrac{e^{2x}}{x^2} - \dfrac{e^x}{x^3} + \dfrac{c_1}{x^2} + \dfrac{c_2}{x^3}$$
This has a pole at $x=0$ unless $c_1 = c_2 = 1$, in which case
$\lim_{x \to 0} y = 2/3$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} y' = 2/3$.  So with the given initial condition there is no solution.